# dateparser throws regex._regex_core.error

Tags: python, string, date, dateparser

I am trying to run a very basic script:

```
import dateparser

dateparser.parse('12/12/12')
```

but I keep getting the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../app/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    dateparser.parse('12/12/12')
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateparser/conf.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateparser/__init__.py", line 61, in parse
    data = parser.get_date_data(date_string, date_formats)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 428, in get_date_data
    parsed_date = _DateLocaleParser.parse(
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 178, in parse
    return instance._parse()
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 182, in _parse
    date_data = self._parsers[parser_name]()
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 196, in _try_freshness_parser
    return freshness_date_parser.get_date_data(self._get_translated_date(), self._settings)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 234, in _get_translated_date
    self._translated_date = self.locale.translate(
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateparser/languages/locale.py", line 131, in translate
    relative_translations = self._get_relative_translations(settings=settings)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateparser/languages/locale.py", line 158, in _get_relative_translations
    self._generate_relative_translations(normalize=True))
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateparser/languages/locale.py", line 172, in _generate_relative_translations
    pattern = DIGIT_GROUP_PATTERN.sub(r'?P<n>\d+', pattern)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/regex/regex.py", line 700, in _compile_replacement_helper
    is_group, items = _compile_replacement(source, pattern, is_unicode)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/regex/_regex_core.py", line 1736, in _compile_replacement
    raise error("bad escape \\%s" % ch, source.string, source.pos)
regex._regex_core.error: bad escape \d at position 7
```

Could it be a compatibility version between dateparser and python?
I am using dateparser 1.1 and python 3.9 and the documentation of dateparsers says that it accepts this python versoin.

Answer (score 9):

Our team just experienced this exact issue which took down our production servers. Last night, one of the dependencies of `dateparser`, `regex` [was updated](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#history) to version `2022.3.15`. Dateparser installs regex, [but without a frozen version](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/blob/4490ca6de44f2e9771e2017e0695f7d9f2d7207e/setup.py#L30). It seems that the newest version of regex does not like something that dateparser is doing, leading to the error you saw.
By pip installing `regex==2022.3.2` before dateparser, this completely fixed our issue.

Comment: Do you have any other comments about this?  I'm having an issue where I'm able to use a module that relies on dateparser/regex in the terminal but when I try to use it in Anaconda, I keep getting the error.  I tried moving the related folders between site-packages directories and still get the error.  And of course I tried your answer of installing `regex==2022.3.2` before installing dateparser.

Comment: Turned out to be more my lack of knowledge with Anaconda.  Just needed to update all conda packages and then get the correct version (still `<2022-3.15`) also through conda.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Happened same with me, app was working on my local dev machine but broke in production due to docker image being updated while I fix other bug. I updated to next version of date-parser and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how I would get by without [`dateutil`](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil)!

Try this:

`python -m pip install python-dateutil`

or conda-forge or whatever (it's not in the standard libarary), and then:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse
>>> date_parse('12/12/12')
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 12, 0, 0)
```

If you have `pandas`, `dateutil` is already installed as a dependency.

Comment: I up-voted this answer because dateparser causes problems in zipapp applications, throwing a regex error

Answer (score 0):

Since you are providing an awkward format I would consider setting the formatting for it

```
dateparser.parse('12/12/1212', date_formats=['%m/%d/%Y'])
```